# How do I get Windows 10 to respect my IPv6 Interface metric?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, routing, ipv6

On a Window 10 system, I have multiple interfaces.  I have assigned route metrics for both IPv4, and IPv6 for each interface. My IPv4 metric is used when I look at the route table.  For IPv6 my metric is ignored, and the wrong interface is selected for outgoing connections.

[image: IPv4 metric]

[image: IPv6 metric]

```
PS C:\users\Public> Get-NetRoute -DestinationPrefix '0.0.0.0/0' | Format-Table -AutoSize

ifIndex DestinationPrefix NextHop      RouteMetric PolicyStore
------- ----------------- -------      ----------- -----------
6       0.0.0.0/0         10.0.0.1             768 ActiveStore
3       0.0.0.0/0         192.168.8.1          512 ActiveStore
4       0.0.0.0/0         192.168.32.1           0 ActiveStore


PS C:\users\Public> Get-NetRoute -DestinationPrefix '::/0' | Format-Table -AutoSize

ifIndex DestinationPrefix NextHop                   RouteMetric PolicyStore
------- ----------------- -------                   ----------- -----------
6       ::/0              fe80::7acd:8eff:fe45:1352         256 ActiveStore
3       ::/0              fe80::20d:b9ff:fe24:78f4          256 ActiveStore
4       ::/0              fe80::208:a2ff:fe09:9119          256 ActiveStore
```

What do I need to do to get Windows to respect my IPv6 route metrics?

Comment: Good question, but... do you need this at all? Are all three interfaces actually connected to the Internet?

Comment: Yes, all 3 have valid internet connectivity.  If I disable 2 of the 3 interfaces, the non disabled one works fine. One link is a fast, but unreliable Comcast connection (metric=0), one is a slow, inexpensive, but very stable DSL (metric=512) connection.  The third, which isn't always active, is a Wireless connection (metric 768)  that will tether to my iPhone data plan.  When Comcast craps out, I want to be able to remove my default routes for the Comcast connection, but leave the Comcast connected interface up.

Comment: Oh, and yes, I know I am making things overly complicated, and I can get most of the same results by manipulating my routers. But it sure seems should be possible to set a route metric on Windows.  Hrm, I wonder if Windows will respect and use a `AdvDefaultPreference` set in radvd.